# AngularJS errors.angularjs.org - error documentation link gets 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm adding a provider to my Angular 1.6.6 project as:

```
angular.module('mymodule').provider('foo', function() { return {}});
```

That's it, I'm not even instantiating the provider in config, just declaring it in my source and it breaks my code. The weird part is that by clicking on the console link that usually opens the Angular error page, now it goes to a 404 error:

**copied directly from console**

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=demo&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DgwApiClient%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Apget%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.6%252F%2524injector%252Fpget%253Fp0%253Dfoo%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A76%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520c%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A402)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.provider%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A312)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520d%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A237)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A358%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A322%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A70%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A322%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20hb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332

Comment: Provider 'foo' must define $get factory method << you better copy this line from console

Comment: @PetrAveryanov any ideas why it goes to a 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Failed to instantiate module demo due to:
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=g...)
>     at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:7:76
>     at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:43:70
>     at p (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:8:7)
>     at g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:42:138)
>     at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:42:322
>     at p (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:8:7)
>     at g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:42:138)
>     at hb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:46:250)
>     at c (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:22:19)
>     at Uc (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js:22:332
> ```

See fixed link below --

Changed `errors.angularjs.org` to `docs.angularjs.org/error`

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=demo&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DgwApiClient%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Apget%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.6%252F%2524injector%252Fpget%253Fp0%253Dfoo%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A76%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520c%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A402)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.provider%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A312)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520d%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A237)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A358%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A322%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.6%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A70%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A322%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20hb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332